# Get the path to the 64-bit Program Files folder

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

I'm using Windows 7 (x64) and I require the path to my 64-bit Program Files folder.

To that end I tried using the `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` method, but but both examples below return the path the the 32-bit Progrom Files folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)`).

```
pfPath = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
pfPath = Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%")
```

I've also tried reading the registry value of `ProgramFilesDir`, but that returns the path of the 32-bit folder as well, despite the key actually containing the correct path (I've checked the registry).

```
pfPath = Shell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir")
```

Is there another way of doing this that may yeild the correct path?

Comment: Sounds as though you're running the 32-bit of the scripting engine for some reason.  If you can correct that, you should get the results you were expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is running on WOW64. Use the `ProgramW6432` environment variable to get the real x64 program files path when your program is running 32-bit.

Note that this environment variable only exists when the program is executing under WOW64. If you expect your program to also run on x86 Windows, you need to use the plain `PROGRAMFILES` environment variable.

So, try `ProgramW6432`, else fall back to `PROGRAMFILES`. There may be a more practical way to determine if the OS is x64 or not with VBScript that you can also use.